# Terraform module throws error "literal not terminated"

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

when i am applying terraform plan it is showing Error loading configuration:Error parsing "Location" 2:21: literal not terminated

template file

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "${var.region}"
}

resource "aws_instance" "modDem" {
  ami           = "${var.ami`enter code here`i}"
  instance_type = "{var.instance}"

  tags {
    Name = "Demo"
  }
}
```

variable file

```
variable "amii" {
  default = "ami-22b9a343"
}

variable "instance" {
  default = "t2.micro"
}

variable "region" {
  default = "us-west-2"
}
```

Module file :

```
module "Tr" {
  source = "../modules'
}
```

Comment: The module's source opens with `"` and closes with `'`, you'll need to change that source to ... `source= "../modules"` so that the source is a properly declared string i.e. it is surrounded by opening and closing `"`.

Answer (score 0):

The `source` field in the Module file is not terminated correctly. It should look this like:
Module File:

```
module "Tr" {
  source = "../modules"
}
```